# Jenkins with groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm using groovy to get some parameters to run jobs in jenkins.

My question is why script A work's and B and C don't

**A**

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
def proc = 'ls -D --format=single-column /path/folder'.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println "out> $sout err> $serr"
return sout.tokenize()
```

**B** *The \\ is to escape \*

```
def proc = 'find /path/folder/ -type f \\( -iname \\*.ear -o -iname \\*.war \\)'.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println "out> $sout err> $serr"
return sout.tokenize()
```

**C** *script.sh return a list of files*

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
def proc = '/scripts/script.sh'.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println "out> $sout err> $serr"
return sout.tokenize()
```

There is some jenkins restriction  to run scripts from groovy or certainly shell  commands?

Comment: In what way do the scripts not work?

Comment: B and C doens't show anything, In the jenkins log I can see the list generated (_println "out> $sout err> $serr"_) but I got nothing in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries I can make this work.

```
if (Origem.equals('FILE')) {
def cmd = ["/bin/bash","-c","/opt/scripts/SearchPackage.sh"]
def sout = new StringBuffer()
def serr = new StringBuffer()
def proc = cmd.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput ( sout, serr )
proc.waitForProcessOutput ()
return sout.tokenize()
}
```

Groovy was not recognizing the // character as an escape for '/'. I just decide  put everything in a shell script and use groovy to call this script. THe problem was solved but if someone has a better aproach I will be glad.